# mysql join master table with another by foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my  MySQL database I have one master table with PK `id_duel` and another table with PK  `id_duel_player` and two FK's `id_player` and `id_duel`.

For every `id_duel` I have two players with the same `id_duel` (two players make one duel).

I want to build this statement:  Give me the duel (`id_duel`) consisted of this two players (`$id_player1`and `$id_player2`- this are id_player of two different players that participated in required duel)

[image: mySql tables]

Can anyone help my with SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a `JOIN` to make sure the two players have the same `id_duel`:

```
SELECT id_duel
FROM duels d
INNER JOIN duel_player dp1
  ON d.id_duel = dp1.id_duel
    AND dp1.id_player = @id_player1
INNER JOIN duel_player dp2
  ON d.id_duel = dp2.id_duel
    AND dp2.id_player = @id_player2
```

Comment: What exactly prevents this query from returning duplicate results in different order? IE: Player1 VS Player2 AND Player2 VS Player1 or is this expected?

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that order wasn't important -- the focus was on finding any duels that have exactly these two players.